# Hidden .DS_Store files not appearing in Finder despite enabling display of hidden files

Tags: terminal, finder, macos

Hidden `.DS_Store` files are appearing in Terminal when using `ls -a` command, but not in Finder.

I have tried used keyboard shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>, which toggles display of other hidden files and directories such as `.gitginore` and `.git` in Finder, but does not do so for `.DS_Store` files.

What is going wrong?

Comment: I use [muCommander](http://www.mucommander.com) for various reasons and it shows .DS_Store files. It does require a Java Runtime Environment (JRE) 1.8 or later. There may be other file managers that do not require Java and can show all hidden files even .DS_Store files. Note: I'm not affiliated with the developer of muCommander.

Comment: What OS version, please?

Comment: Check this [site](https://appletoolbox.com/mac-os-x-how-to-remove-ds_store-files/) for more information about what `DS_Store` files are and how to deal with them.

Comment: The logic behind most Apple's choices is going wrong...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.DS_Store` are special metadata files created automatically by Finder.app.

Finder.app is programmed to keep `.DS_Store` files hidden even when using the <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> keyboard shortcut to toggle display of hidden files.

Since they are not user managed files and are intended to be used internally by Finder, they are not treated like other hidden files and kept hidden despite using the said shortcut.

The aforementioned is w.r.t. macOS Mojave 10.14.4.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks. And thanks for editing my question to make it clearer :) So in conclusion, the only way to see if I have DS_Store files is using terminal, there is no way to make it visible in Finder? Are there are any other files in Terminal that are not visible, ever?

Comment: @SimonKones Yes. I am not aware of any other hidden files with similar behaviour.

Comment: This might need a version specification; IIRC, I can often view those files and needed to teach myself not to move them when drag-and-dropping large numbers of files around the Dropbox folder...

Comment: This answer is inaccurate. These files may be viewed in finder; see [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/355895/116377)

Comment: Just adding that it's not just the file name. Copying .DS_Store (cp .DS_Store mds_store.txt) will also produce a hidden file to the Finder. Also running 'chflags nohiden' is not working on the files. Possibly has some new flag.

Comment: @user3.1415927 If you check the comments on that answer, it seems that from Mojave onwards, .DS_Store is ignored by this command. I can verify that it doesn't work on Ventura.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what command the <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shft</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> shortcut invokes, but to truly show hidden files (on 10.9.* through 10.13.*, as of today), use terminal to execute:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE; killall Finder
```

For 10.6.* through 10.8.*, use (note the capitalization difference in the first instance of `Finder`):

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE; killall Finder
```

Source: http://osxdaily.com/2009/02/25/show-hidden-files-in-os-x/
(I'm definitely not a fan of osxdaily.com, but it works.

Additionally, to check on your current value, use

```
defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles
```

... and for simple usage of the `defaults` command, just enter `defaults` with no arguments.

I verified that the value on this system is set to `TRUE` and I can see all the .DS_Store files as seen below... (using 10.11.6)

[image: hidden files visible]

Comment: The mentioned commands doesn't appear to work under macOS Mojave.

Comment: No indication of os version in question.

Comment: I have edited my answer and added a note mentioning the behaviour as it works in macOS Mojave.

Comment: Doesn't appear to work on Monterey.

Comment: Doesn't work on Ventura either. It seems that from Mojave onwards, .DS_Store is ignored by this command.

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work. I'm on Sonoma.

Answer (score 0):

A non Finder way of finding the file. The file is displayed in the terminal. Use the `ls -a` command and you'll see it.

Comment: This is what the poster says in their first sentence.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri A lot of people don't bother reading the question and skip straight to the answers.